# oracle alter sequence by shell script & sqlplus

Tags: oracle, shell, variables, sqlplus

I'm working on altering sequence through sqlplus in a shell script. 
What I'm about to do is to get the max seq_no of the table, set the value in v_increment_num, and increase the sequence by v_increment_num. But it gets an error when alter statement runs.

### The script is like below.

```
echo start load_my_adm_user.sh

sqlplus myId/myPassword <<EOF

set echo on
set time on
set timing on
set serveroutput on
spool TB_MY_ADM_USER.log

var v_increment_num varchar2(1000);

SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) INTO :v_increment_num FROM TB_MY_ADM_USER;
alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by v_increment_num;
select mydb.SQ_ADM_USER.nextval from dual;
alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by 1;

spool off
EOF
exit
```

---

### and the running result(TB_MY_ADM_USER.log) is like:

```
07:01:23 SQL> SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) INTO :v_increment_num FROM TB_MY_ADM_USER;

MAX(SEQ_NO)
-----------
          4

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
07:01:23 SQL>
07:01:23 SQL> alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by v_increment_num;
alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by v_increment_num
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
07:01:23 SQL>
07:01:23 SQL> select mydb.SQ_ADM_USER.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        19

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
07:01:23 SQL> alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by 1;

Sequence altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

---

What exactly am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost everything correct, just have to remember that DDL statements, i.e. `alter sequence`, too, don't work with bind variables. Which, I mean a bind variable, is what your `v_increment_num` is.

If SQL*Plus is what you're going to use, then try it with its own substitution "variables", i.e. the "ampersand"-variables...

```
echo start load_my_adm_user.sh

sqlplus myId/myPassword <<EOF

set echo on
set time on
set timing on
set serveroutput on
spool TB_MY_ADM_USER.log

-- do not do...
-- var v_increment_num varchar2(1000);
-- do instead...
column max_seq_no new_val v_increment_num
-- note: this makes all MAX_SEQ_NO column values from all subsequent SELECTs to be stored in the &V_INCREMENT_NUM variable

-- do not do...
-- SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) INTO :v_increment_num FROM TB_MY_ADM_USER;
-- do instead...
SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) as max_seq_no FROM TB_MY_ADM_USER;
-- note: at this point, you will have your MAX(SEQ_NO) value stored in your &V_INCREMENT_NUM variable

-- do not do...
-- alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by v_increment_num;
-- do instead...
alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by &v_increment_num;

select mydb.SQ_ADM_USER.nextval from dual;
alter sequence mydb.SQ_ADM_USER increment by 1;

spool off
EOF
exit
```

**Note:** I did not try this particular code, just wrote it here directly, so it may not be working at the first attempt, but we'll get that eventuality sorted out later.

Comment: It perfectly works.. learned how to use new_value parameter. Thanks a lot!